# How to Recompile an old lib file

Tags: c++, lib

I am trying to build a C++ project, that was created in 2003, in VS2015. Whenever I try to build the project, I get the following Linker Tool Errors on one of the lib files:

[LNK2026](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/100ezk17.aspx)
[LNK1281](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afa9eakh(v=vs.90).aspx)

From all the research I've done, it looks like the lib file is outdated and needs to be recompiled using a new toolkit. However, I'm not sure which toolkit I should use. Does anybody know how to recompile an old lib file?

Comment: You can't recompile the lib itself. You need the source code.

Comment: Those are both related to SafeSEH. You can turn that off in your current project and you may be able to link to the lib then if you do not have the source code to recompile it.

Comment: It seems to me that you can try and remove the /SAFESEH flag from the compiler and try again

Comment: I tried to turn off /SAFESEH, but I get the Error [LNK2019](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx) when I do

Comment: edit: "If /SAFESEH:NO is specified, the linker will not produce an image with a table of safe exceptions handlers even if all modules are compatible with the safe exception handling feature."

Comment: If you remove /SAFESEH, then it will try to produce safe exception handler table, so specify /SAFESEH:NO ;)

Comment: "If /SAFESEH is not specified, the linker will produce an image with a table of safe exceptions handlers if all modules are compatible with the safe exception handling feature."

Comment: Binaries produced by VC++ compilers of different major versions cannot be linked together. They are not ABI-compatible. Even if you figure out safeseh issue, linker will miss some symbols, and even if you figure out this, the behavior of program is still undefined. Forget the idea. You either need source code for the library or to use the same compiler with which it was built back then.